# Unable to update database when user confirms their email

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am trying to implement email confirmation on my project. I sign a JWT which is sent in an email using nodemailer. After the link is clicked the JWT is sent to the server for processing. I am able to find out if the JWT matches the one generated by the server. However I am now struggling with updating the database to store that the user has confirmed the email.

Controller

```
    confirmEmail = async (req, res, next) => {

        this.checkValidation(req)

        const { email } = req.body
        const param = req.params.token
    

        const user = await userModel.findOne({ email })


        if(!user)
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, 'User not found')
        }

        if(user.confired)
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, 'User already confirmed')
        }

        if(!user.confirmed)
        {
            const confirmJWT = jwt.verify(param, process.env.SECRET_JWT)
            if(!confirmJWT)
            {
                throw new HttpException(200, 'Token failed')
            }
            
            const result = await userModel.emailConfirmed(email)
            throw new HttpException(401, 'User not cofirmed')
        }


    }
```

Model

```
    emailConfirmed = async({email}) => {
        const sql = `UPDATE ${this.tableName} SET confirmed = true WHERE email = ?`

        const result = await query(sql, email)

        return result
    }
```

[Error] Error: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
this is the error I get when attempting to change the db.

Comment: `async({email}) => {` says the caller is sending an object that has an email property, but the caller looks like it's just sending an  email string.  Also, shouldn't the sql string read `... WHERE email = ${email}` ?

Comment: I thought if I don't use the ? and allow the use to ${email} it opens up for SQL injection?

Comment: You are right. I didn’t read it carefully enough.